# go downloaded with apt,but go command not found

Tags: linux, go

my os is Kali.First i enter `go`,shell told me `go command not found`

```
└─$ go       
Command 'go' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install gccgo-go 
sudo apt install golang-go
```

so i `sudo apt install golang-go` and it told me golang-go is already latest version,but `go` was still not found.And i google to knows sometime it will have a floder `/usr/local/go` but it not have one.

```
┌──(highway㉿highway)-[/usr/local]
└─$ ll       
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096  5月 16 13:27 bin
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096  2月  8 01:26 etc
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096  2月  8 01:26 games
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096  2月  8 01:26 include
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096  4月 23 17:28 lib
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    9  4月 23 17:28 man -> share/man
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096  4月 24 08:09 samba
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096  2月  8 01:26 sbin
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096  4月 24 08:09 share
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096  2月  8 01:26 src
```

so i `locate go` and find `/usr/lib/go` and `cd /usr/lib/go/bin`

```
┌──(highway㉿highway)-[/usr/lib/go]
└─$ ls             
api  bin  doc  misc  pkg  src  test  VERSION

┌──(highway㉿highway)-[/usr/lib/go/bin]
└─$ ll
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 10225816  5月 15 03:22 go
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  2281848  5月 15 03:22 gofmt

┌──(highway㉿highway)-[/usr/lib/go/bin]
└─$ ./go version  
go version go1.18.2 linux/amd64

┌──(highway㉿highway)-[/usr/lib/go/bin]
└─$ ./go env     
GO111MODULE=""
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/home/highway/.cache/go-build"
GOENV="/home/highway/.config/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOEXPERIMENT=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOINSECURE=""
GOMODCACHE="/home/highway/go/pkg/mod"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/highway/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/lib/go-1.18"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/go-1.18/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GOVCS=""
GOVERSION="go1.18.2"
GCCGO="gccgo"
GOAMD64="v1"
AR="ar"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/dev/null"
GOWORK=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build3356979286=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

it work,but why `go` is still not found?

```
┌──(highway㉿highway)-[/usr/lib/go/bin]
└─$ go   
Command 'go' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install gccgo-go 
sudo apt install golang-go
```

what different between floder `/usr/lib/go/bin` and `/usr/local/go`?if there were not different what can i do to use `go` instead of `cd /usr/lib/go/bin && ./go`.

Comment: https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/ - "The fact of the matter is, [...] it is **NOT** a recommended distribution if you’re unfamiliar with Linux". I strongly recommend that you consider an alternative distribution, given that it sounds like you're not very familiar with Linux. You can fix this immediate problem by adding an alias for `go` or adding the parent directory to your `$PATH`.

Comment: @asked just checkout your `env` environment variable PATH and Bash aliases.... After remove unused go location or alias.

Answer (score 2):

You need to append go's bin directory to your PATH environment variable. Add this line at the end of `~/.bashrc`:

`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/go/bin`

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to @emilianolch solution is to create symlinks in `/usr/local/bin`. And you properly want all the binaries in `/usr/lib/go/bin` linked, so:

```bash
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/go/bin/* /usr/lib/bin/
```

Should work right away without restarting terminal.

PRO: `Go` binaries appear as they are like other distro. May work better with other tools like VS Code SSH Remote.

CON: Have to `ln` again if more `Go` tools are installed via `apk` in future. (Only new ones, not needed if reinstalling/upgrading existing ones)